# why django-stdimage not rendering in my html template?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

Why image is not rendering in my html template? here is my code:

**#models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from stdimage import StdImageField

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = StdImageField(upload_to="contact/images/",variations={'thumbnail':(640,480)})
```

**#settings.py**
added 'stdimage' in my apps

#html

```
{{myimagefield.thumbnail}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I did mistake. Instead of `{{myimagefield.thumbnail}}` I need to be use `{{contact.image.thumbnail}}` in my template. Where contact is my model class name and image is my field name.

**One important note:** The variations add to the image being uploaded, not replace. See the 4th bullet point at the top of the [docs 2](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage).